# Access violation writing location error when using strcat

Tags: c++, c

I am having problems when using the strcat function in C++.

If I do :

```
MyClass::MyClass(char* myString){

char* AnotherString = myString;
strcat(AnotherString, "bob");

}
```

Then everything is fine.  However, if I do:

```
MyClass::MyFunction(){

char* AnotherString = "fred";
strcat(AnotherString, "bob");

}
```

I get an unhandled exception in strcat.asm.  Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: Why are you using C-Strings in C++ code?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: The question is tagged C++ not C. Since they are completely different languages why would you rely on functionality that belongs to another language. Its like using C-Strings in Java/C#/Python/Ruby/Php/Perl. Why would you do that. Also the C++ language designers provided a perfectly good string class in the standard library so why use a string class provided by another language.

Comment: @Martin Why would you do that? Well maybe because C-Strings are part of the C++ standard.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: You are under the misconception that C++ and C are the same language. If the question had been tagged C you may have had a fighting chance of winning the argument (you would still have lost). But since you are plainly in this conversation purely (and puerile) to provoke a flame response (based on your totally inadequate answer and silly responses below) I think we can leave it there.

Comment: @Martin Uh? I guess you are not aware that C-String actually work differently in C and C++, so I'm not sure what you meant by the same language part. All language features are situational. Sometimes it is better to use `char*` sometimes it is better to use `std::string`. Specific code behaviour can be almost always achieved by using different features of the language that have different strengths and weaknesses. That's the beauty of C++.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding a C tag to the question, because the reason the OP was crashing is also of interest to C students. Thought I'd comment here since there seems to be a bit of a row about that.

Comment: I am actually passing the result to an external C library which is the reason I'm using char*.

Comment: @paj7777 OK then. The basic principle is: "never store a string literal as `char*`" If you need to, make a copy using `strdup()`. And if you make a copy, don't forget to free the memory.

Comment: @paj7777 That's not a good reason. You could use the `c_str()` member function, which returns a pointer to char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the compiler shouldn't allow you to compile this (without warnings):

```
char* str = "fred";
```

The correct code is:

```
const char* str = "fred";
```

String literals are constants, therefore you can't modify their contents.

Comment: As unfortunate as it may seem, `char* str = "fred";` is actually well-formed and standard compliant, because there is a (deprecated) conversion of string literals to pointers to non-const characters in C++, inherited from C.

Comment: strcat takes a char* as the first argument, you can't pass a const char* as the first argument to the strcat function.

Comment: @paj7777 Well that's the problem, you are passing a `const char*`

Comment: @usta Nope. From C++ standard (revision from 2003): "An ordinary string literal has type “array of n const char” and static storage duration (3.7),"

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: 4.2/2: "A string literal (2.13.4) that is not a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to
char”; a wide string literal can be converted to an rvalue of type “pointer to wchar_t”. In either case,
the result is a pointer to the first element of the array. This conversion is considered only when there is an
explicit appropriate pointer target type, and not when there is a general need to convert from an lvalue to an
rvalue. [Note: this conversion is deprecated. See Annex D. ]"

Comment: The conversion from string literal to non-const character pointer only produces a warning, not an error, due to the reason @usta mentions.

Comment: @usta Oh thx, I missed that. Anyway the compiler should still note that it is deprecated.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: No I'm not. I'm passing it a char*, if I were passing a const char* then it wouldn't let me compile, contrary to your post.

Comment: @paj7777 OK. One more time. String literals are `const char *`. You can convert them into `char *` but that won't change the fact, that they are `const char*` and can't be modified. Therefore if you do `char *str = "bla"; str[0] = 'B';` it will most likely crash.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Ok, maybe you'd like to tell me what this has to do with my issue, I'm obviously missing something.

Comment: @paj7777 `strcat()` takes `char*` as the first parameter, you are passing a `const char*` (which you converted into `char*`).

Comment: @usta You are wrong. That is ill formed, and depreciated. If you are not getting a warning, then change the compiler.

Comment: @VJo: No I am not wrong. You seem to confuse notions of 'ill-formed', 'deprecated', and 'getting a warning'. Something cannot be both ill-formed and deprecated, for instance. Also warnings are implementation specific and in no way affect or determine standard compliance.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be:  String literals *should* be `const char *`.  They aren't, for historical reasons.  Instead, they're usable as `char *` with the proviso that attempting to modify one is undefined behavior.  Therefore, saying that they can't be modified is precisely as correct as saying they can't be unmodifiable, and I've worked on enough implementations where modifying such strings works.  A conforming compiler is required to compile `char * str = "Fred";`.  It would be nice if it gave a warning, but that's a quality of implementation issue.

Comment: @David String literals are `const char*` well, array of `const char` to be precise. They just can be implicitly converted (which is deprecated) to `char *`. I would be interested to know what platforms allow writing into string literals (I have seen some, where the code doesn't crash, but has no effect).

Comment: Anyway, after all this debate and after I finally understood what Let_Me_Be was trying to explain I've finally solved issure....kind of.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be:  Typically, altering a string literal will work just fine on a general-purpose computer with no memory protection.  ("Just fine" here does not consider unintended consequences.)  I wrote a lot of C and C++ code on pre-OSX Macintoshes, for example.  Again, it's one of those cases where some systems would have to go to some trouble to prevent it, some would have to go to some trouble to allow it, it's a bad idea no matter what, so it becomes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 10):

### The answer you need...

is to use C++:

```
std::string anotherString = "fred";
anotherString += "bob";
```

### The answer you probably want...

is what both Let_Me_Be and Moo-Juice said, combined.

This bit of code:

```
char* anotherString = "fred";
```

is extremely dangerous and should by all means be avoided. `fred` is stored in a read-only section of the memory and cannot be changed -- it is essentially the same as a `const char*` for all pratical purposes. Note that `char anotherString[] = "fred";` is a whole different story, as it actually stores a *copy* of `fred`, which can be modified at will.

However, as Moo-Juice pointed out, `strcat` concatenates the second argument **after the first one**, which means the first string must have enough allocated room to hold both of them. So in your case, `char anotherString[] = "fred";` would do you no good, as `anotherString` would only be 5 bytes long. You should then write:

```
char anotherString[8] = "fred"; // fred + bob + 1
strcat(anotherString, "bob");
```

Of course, in a real world scenario you probably don't know the string sizes in advance, so you'd use `malloc` to allocate an adequated buffer.

Comment: It is allowable to store "fred" in a read-only section of memory.  It is not required.  And please never recommend `malloc()` for a C++ program.

Comment: @David Thornley: I recommended `malloc()` on purpose. If you have `new`, you're in C++; if you're in C++, use `std::string`!

Comment: Thank you for actually explaining the issue. Nowhere in the accepted answer or its comments did anyone mention that you had to allocate enough room to fit both strings.

Answer (score 7):

The buffer pointed to by "dest" in `strcat(dest, src)` must be large enough to hold the resulting string.  So:

```
char* anotherString = "fred"; // 5 bytes including zero-terminator
```

e.g, no room for "Bob".

But, you've posted this in C++ so why are you using strcat() anyway?

```
#include <string>

std::string another = "fred";
another.append("bob");
```

Comment: +1 because c++ strings are so much easier to deal with.  Now I just wish that streams would be as nice as printf

Comment: Also the "fred" string is stored in read-only storage as part of the programs code.  So even if you did: strcpy(anotherString, "bob"); you would get an access volation error.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be or, you could be constructive and point out the errors, as opposed to being belligerent.

Comment: If that's the case then why does the first example work fine given that AnotherString is defined as char* AnotherString; globally.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Try some reading, that would help, the answer I posted would be a good start.

Comment: @paj7777 My guess would be that you are not storing a pointer to  a string literal in the AnotherString variable. If it is a pointer to some writable buffer, that `strcat()` should of course work correctly.

Comment: @GWW: As you like printf, you might want to have a look at [Boost.Format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/format/index.html).

Comment: @usta: That's what I've started to use it's much nicer

Comment: To everyone upvoting Moo-Juice comment, tell me. What should I do next time? Copy-paste my entire answer into the comment?

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Maybe you should be more concerned with updating your answer than being pissed off about Moo-Juice getting upvotes. The first sentence `First, the compiler shouldn't allow you to compile this` is incorrect; compilation succeeds, albeit with a warning (on GCC). VS2010 doesn't generate a warning even at the Level4 warning setting.

Comment: @Praetorian I don't consider a compilation with warnings a successful compilation. The fact that VS2010 doesn't report this as an error/warning is pitiful, but not really unexpected.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Agreed that it is pitiful that VS2010 isn't emitting a warning, but maybe the OP is using the VC++ compiler and not seeing any warnings. Also, I consider your answer to be the correct one if you'd just modify the first statement. Sure, we should all be setting the `Treat warnings as errors` option but sometimes you just can't get away from warnings - when using automated code generation tools, for instance.

Comment: @Praetorian OK, I added the without warnings part.

Comment: @paj7777 It appears to work but it is still wrong.  Invalid memory operations are not always detected by the compiler\run time. I bet in a more complicated function it wouldn't work as well.